# Stuck on getting the rows to align, am I doing something wrong?

Tags: mysql

I have two tables, Grouptable and GroupSet

in Grouptable, there are GroupID, GroupName and GroupBudget

in GroupSet, its made of composite foreign made of two set of GroupID, one named GroupSetID and the other name SubGroupID

I'm trying to print the GroupSet details and columns with the highest budget subgroup and its details.

My output does not seem to want to marry up with what I expect to see... The GroupSet itself part is fine but the subgroup data is incorrect, the highest budget column is fine but the subgroupID and its name don't match at all... any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
select g1.GroupID, gt2.groupname, gt2.budget, 
g1.subgroupID, gt.groupname, max(gt1.budget)
from groupset g1, 
grouptable gt1, 
groupset g2, 
grouptable gt2
where g1.subgroupID=gt1.groupID
and g1.groupID=gt2.groupID
group by g1.groupID;
```

Comment: That said, this is the most frequently asked question under this tag.

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to get the columns to line up with a join, rather than selecting separately from the tables. For example:

```
select (g.GroupID, gt.groupname, gt.budget, 
g.subgroupID,  max(gt.budget))
from groupset g left join grouptable gt on g.groupID = gt.groupID 
where g.subgroupID=gt.groupID
and g.groupID=gt.groupID
order by g.groupID asc;
```